# How to lock a sql login after N unsuccessful login attempts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, logins, password

Consider I have login called sql_login. Can I lock `sql_login` login after `5` unsuccessful login attempts.

When we create a login we can see there is option called [password policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161959.aspx) check the image. But there is nothing mentioned about locking password

[image]

Is there a option in Sql Server to lock a login after `N` unsuccessful login attempts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can but you have to set everything up.

## SQL Server (SQL) Login

When you enable the `Enforce password policy` option in the SQL Server Login window, you are basically telling the SQL Server to adhere either to the local security policy or to the policy defined in the domain.

> The enforcement of password policy can be configured separately for each SQL Server login. Use ALTER LOGIN (Transact-SQL) to configure the password policy options of a SQL Server login. The following rules apply to the configuration of password policy enforcement:
>
> - When CHECK_POLICY is changed to ON, the following behaviors occur:
>
>   - CHECK_EXPIRATION is also set to ON unless it is explicitly set to OFF.
>   - The password history is initialized with the value of the current password hash.
>   - Account lockout duration, account lockout threshold, and reset account lockout counter after are also enabled.

and also:

> The security policy might be set in Windows, or might be received from the domain. To view the password policy on the computer, use the Local Security Policy MMC snap-in (secpol.msc).

Reference: [Password Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161959(v=sql.110).aspx) (MSDN / SQL Server 2012)

## Setting Policy (locally)

So if you require an account to be locked out after 3 wrong tries, then you either have to define a local policy with `secpol.msc` or define a domain policy for account lockout.

#### Example in secpol.msc

[image: local secpol.msc window displaying lockout policy settings]

SQL Server will then use this policy if the `Enforce password policy` option is checked.

A technical overview of the account lockout policy can be found here:

Reference: [Account Lockout Policy Technical Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh994566(WS.10).aspx) (MSDN)
Reference: [Account lockout threshold](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh994574(v=ws.10).aspx) (MSDN)

## Locked out SQL Login

Here is what happens after a SQL Login has been locked out after the set amount of incorrect logins (15 in my case as domain policy). You can see the `Login is locked out` is set. This can be unset to unblock the account.

[image: SQL Login with locked out status after 15 attempts]